# How to enter a number separated per three digits into a function

Tags: javascript, integer

I am using a function where large integers are passed as a parameter.

For example.

```
doSomethingWithInteger(1234567890)
```

However, it's a little difficult to keep track of the place value of integer (and thus its value), if I do something like this:

```
doSomethingWithInteger(101934109348)
```

How many digits, and thus what is the actual value of that integer really? It's hard to keep track. Obviously the following example blows up with an error because it's interpreted as multiple arguments:

```
doSomethingWithInteger(101 934 109 348)
```

But is there a way to achieve some effect like that in JS to make the amount of digits, and thus the value of the integer more clear?

Edit: To clarify, I'm having trouble keeping track of the value of the numbers by not being able to track the place values, and not having trouble determining the length of the string.

Comment: What's the point of the question, are *you* having trouble identifying the number of digits/characters in a sequence, or is it programmatic difficulty (somehow)?

Comment: @DavidThomas I've updated the question hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no solution built in to the syntax but I suppose you could do something this with a function.

```
function toInt(arr) {
  return parseInt(arr.join(''));
}

toInt([123, 456, 7890]); // 1234567890
doSomethingWithInteger(toInt([101, 934, 109, 348]));
```

This works by taking in an array, combining the entire array into a single string, then casting that string to an integer. Obviously you'll incur a performance hit with this.

Comment: Yeah I knew it was a longshot but I thought maybe there was some syntax magic to help keep track of place values. Yes I suppose I could use a helper function but I'll probably avoid adding the complexity, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know the number of digits that has the int?
You can get it by doing this:

`(12324897928).toString().length`